# How to smooth interpolation of a float array into a bigger array?

Tags: swift, interpolation, cubic-spline, vdsp, accelerate

I'm stuck with interpolation in Swift. Can anyone help me with that?

I want to interpolate the float array (say `[0, 0, 100, 25, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0, 0]`) into another array with some given size (for example **128**). I found an article ([Use Linear Interpolation to Construct New Data Points](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/use_linear_interpolation_to_construct_new_data_points)) that shows, how to achieve this stuff.

There are two ways (you can see the results below, how they perform):

- Linear Interpolation using `vDSP_vgenp` and
- Smoother (but not for my purposes) Interpolation using `vDSP_vlint`

The problem is both techniques don't realize my expectations, which illustrated in [Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVxFP.png). How can I make my *interpolated* distribution smoother? I want to see a **cube-like curve**.

**Initial Plot:**

[image: Screenshot 1]

**Linear Interpolation:**

```swift
import Accelerate

let n = vDSP_Length(128)
let stride = vDSP_Stride(1)

let values: [Float] = [0, 0, 100, 25, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0, 0]
let indices: [Float] = [0, 11, 23, 34, 46, 58, 69, 81, 93, 104, 116]

var result = [Float](repeating: 0, count: Int(n))

vDSP_vgenp(values, stride, indices, stride, &result, stride, n, vDSP_Length(values.count))
```

[image: Screenshot 2]

**Smooth Interpolation:**

```swift
import Accelerate
import AVFoundation

let n = vDSP_Length(1024)
let stride = vDSP_Stride(1)

let values: [Float] = [0, 0, 100, 25, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0, 0]
let denominator = Float(n) / Float(values.count - 1)

let control: [Float] = (0 ... n).map {
    let x = Float($0) / denominator
    return floor(x) + simd_smoothstep(0, 1, simd_fract(x))
}

var result = [Float](repeating: 0, count: Int(n))

vDSP_vlint(values, control, stride, &result, stride, n, vDSP_Length(values.count))
```

[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: I can't help answer your question, but I gotta say, this is a really well asked question, particularly for a first time poster! Clear question, demonstration of effort, example of code, actual vs intended outcomes. Well done, and welcome!

Comment: Thank you very much @Alexander-ReinstateMonica! I did my best to demonstrate, what I want to solve ^_^

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the `vDSP_vqint` quadratic interpolation functions would solve the problem. See the discussion at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1449942-vdsp_vqint.

Comment: Possibly. I've seen this function but didn't understand what the parameters should look like. Especially the second one - `_ __B: UnsafePointer<Float>`. They say: "Single-precision real input vector. Integer parts are indices into A and fractional parts are interpolation constants". There is no glue for me, what is *fractional* and what is *integer* parts. Maybe you could explain this?

Comment: The parameters are the same as you used in the linear interpolation function.  The trick is to change your input function and it's coordinates (as well as the desired output coordinates) so that they overlap nicely.  Massage your input function so that it is of the form f(i) where i is a sequence of integers (from 0 to max).  Then massage your desired output function g(j) so that it's coordinates fall along the same axis with values also ranging from 0 to max.  These output-function coordinates will generally each fall somwhere between the integer values used in your input function.

Comment: @aiba Single precision vector and Double precision vector, only means Float and Double.

If you look at the documentation you can see that only the type of pointer change
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1449771-vdsp_vgenp
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1450645-vdsp_vgenpd

I think that's also well explained in the Floating-Point Numbers of the Swift documentation
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

You can also print the value of Float.pi and Double.pi to see what's the difference.

Comment: After for the integer part, that what's before the `,` and fractional is what comes after.

Also, I think in your case you are looking for cubic spline interpolation and not a linear interpolation.

I haven't found how to achieve this using the Accelerate Framework, but here is a library that does the same.

https://github.com/gscalzo/SwiftCubicSpline

Comment: Thank you all for the answers! I went with @Steven's suggestion and used CubicSpline.